# Get the running page in an application

Tags: android

Assume my application contain 3 pages and run that application. In the middle of that application at page 2 i got a phone call and after that phone call again i am starting that application using menu in home screen .At that time i want a page where we stop in previous(that means 2 page).Give me the suggestions Thanks in advance

Comment: I've read it a few times, but I really don't understand your question.  Can try to explain it a little better?

Comment: Do you want to replace the Home screen application?

Answer (score 1):

please read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

from the above link, when an application loses its focus to other application the focus losing application will be kept on stack and again when it gains the focus it resumes from the previous state. In case if your application contains some perishable data you can use the methods `onPause()` when you app loses focus and `onResume()` when your app regains the focus.